# blastp option to compare with a personal database

Tags: blastp, makeblastdb

I'm trying to compare proteins generated with prokka (from a genome) with blastp using a virulence factor database [VFDB](http://www.mgc.ac.cn/VFs/download.htm), and I want to use some parameters obtained from this [paper](https://journals.asm.org/doi/epdf/10.1128/mBio.02852-18):

`blastp option, top hit, ≥50% identity, ≥50% alignment length, E-value of < 10 - 5`

How can I specify those parameters on the command line?

```
# create DB
makeblastdb -in VFDB.fas -dbtype prot

# run blast
blastp -query my.faa -db VFDB.fas -out results.txt .....
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these options:

```
blastp -query my.faa -db VFDB.fas \
       -perc_identity 50 -outfmt 6 \
       -evalue 10e-5 -out results.txt
```

Then select the 5th column, *qlen*, and the 13th columns, *slen*, and get the percentage higher than 50.

```
awk  -F'\t' '{ if ($NF >= 50) printf "%s\t%.2f\n", $0 , ($2/$5)*100 }' result.txt
```

Check the documentation for the full `-outfmt` column names with `blast -help`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. one more questions. I use the outfmt 6, and it have the next columns: qseqid, sseqid, pident, length, mismatch, gapopen, qstart, qend, sstart, send, evalue, bitscore. in this case which columns do I have to use to determinate the percent of alignment length? , thanks so much

Comment: you can configure outfmt 6 to produce a custom format, *qlen* and *slen* included, check the `blastp -help`